# Multiple conditions in my google sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create an application or website that reads the username/password from the Google Sheet as my database.

I keep getting an *ID not Found* response even though the variables match the ID and class.

Once I remove the `&& Classcheck[i][0] == class` and only keep it as just `if (values[i][0] == id)` it works just fine.

It seems I am able to only read 1 variable at a time? I am trying to get both if that's possible.

```
function inTime(e) {

   var id = e.parameter.id;
   var class = e.parameter.class;
   var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
   var Classcheck = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
   var in_time = e.parameter.in_time;

   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

     if (values[i][0] == id && Classcheck[i][0] == class)){
       i = i + 2;
       sheet.getRange(i, 5).setValue(in_time)
       return ContentService.createTextOutput("Welcome to class " + in_time).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
     }
   }
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id Not Found ").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about ``I keep getting an error.``? I think that such information will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Quote the exact error and edit it into your question rather than posting as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think that from your additional information, the query parameters and/or payload when you request to Web Apps are required to be also provided. By the way, when you modify the script of Web Apps, is the Web Apps deployed as new version? By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. But if you are using the script as a library, it is no problem.

Comment: Yes, whenever i make any new changes everything is deployed as a new version.

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the query parameters and/or payload when you request to Web Apps, in your script, ``Classcheck`` is retrieved by ``getValue()``. So only the value of "C2" is retrieved and the value is splitted as every character by ``Classcheck[i][0]``. From this situation, for example, how about modifying to ``var Classcheck = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();``?

Comment: Could you show me an example of what i should change in the script?

Comment: Although I showed the modification point, if you cannot understand my English, I have to apologize.

Comment: `getValue` and `getValues` return very different things.

Comment: ah thank you everyone : ) figured it out. yes it was the not included "s" in values the whole time